# \newcommand{}[1]...[n]{}

Tags: macros

Good evening,
I need to create `\newcommand`s with n-variables like

`\newcommand{text}[1]...[n]{...#1...#n}`.

For example, for `n=2`, I would like to create a `\newcommand`  of type $ \left\|#1\right\|_{#2} $ that denotes a norme in which #1 represents the element on which I'd like to calculate the norme, while #2 rapresents the type of the norme, this is, if #2=1 we have the 1-norme, if #2=2 we have the 2-norme, this is, the Euclidean-norme, if #2=$ \infty $ we have the infinity-norme.

How can I do?

Thank you so much.

Comment: As a rule, `n` cannot exceed a value of 9.  Is that a problem?

Comment: You have misunderstood the syntax of `\newcommand`. Try `\newcommand\norme[2]{$ \left|#1\right|_{#2}$}` etc.

Comment: No, it's not a problem.

Comment: That is not the proper syntax. It is just `[n]` where n can be 0 to 9

Comment: @31415926535897932384 I just edited the question-text.

Comment: @Puck: Can you show some use cases for the macro you want to have? For example, the description in the problem suggests something like `\text{p}{2}`, or `\text{r}{1}`. Can you also supply the expected output?

Comment: If I did this: `\newcommand{\Norme}[2]{\left\|#1\right\|_{#2}}` , is that ok?

Comment: @Puck: Sure! Then you'd use it `\Norme{p}{\infty}`, or `\Norme{r}{2}`...

Comment: Thak you so much

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer if it helped / solved the problem. This is alöos true for your other questions that have answers.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, `\newcommand`'s first optional argument indicates the number of arguments (up to 9) that the command can use. So you actually would write:

```
\newcommand{\commandname}[n]{... #1 ... #n }
```

for the *n* different arguments that you want. A second optional argument indicates that you have an optional argument as argument number 1 and gives its default value.

That said, the preferred way to define new commands in 2021 would be with `\NewDocumentCommand` which has more flexibility in its argument specifications and also makes sure that any commands with fancy logic don't break if they're used in moving arguments¹ like section headers or figure/table captions. For your *n*-argument command you would write

```
 \NewDocumentCommand{\commandname}{ mmmmmm }{ ... #1 ... #n ... }
```

where you have *n* `m`'s in the second argument to `\NewDocumentCommand`. With this, it's also easy to declare optional arguments anywhere in the argument list you like (and have as many as you like). The full info is available by typing `texdoc xparse` at a command line or pulling up the documentation online at https://texdoc.org

---

1, With the effective elimination of fragile commands from LaTeX, there's less need to worry about moving arguments than there had been in the past, but a simple version of what it's about is that fragile commands were (usually) those commands which had some sort of logic inside them, e.g., detecting math mode, or checking for optional arguments and moving arguments were the arguments to those commands whose contents might be used in more than one place (e.g., page headers, the table of contents, list of figures or list of tables), even if they're not actually used there (so just because you don't have a list of figures doesn't make your caption command non-moving).

Comment: You're basically telling me to do something like this: `\NewDocumentCommand{m ... m}[n]{... # 1 ... # n ...}`, isn't it?

Comment: But I don't well understand what the `m`s do...

Comment: No `[n]`. You put one `m` for each **m**andatory argument.

Comment: Therefore, if I wanted to write a `p`-norme, Could I write so?: `\NewDocumentCommand{\Norme}[2]{\left\|#1\right\|}_{#2}`

Comment: Furthermore, Could you take an example with `\NewDocumentCommand{\commandname}{ mmmmmm }{ ... #1 ... #n ... }` in which explain the function of  `m`s? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: `\newcommand{\Norme}[2]` is equivalent to `\NewDocumentCommand{\Norme}{ mm }` You put one `m` for each argument that you want to have.